# Angular Keycloak with own database

Tags: javascript, angular, keycloak

I need to register user in own database after register user with key cloak

Hello little question (I can't find anything on google despite half a day of research)
I have an angular application which uses Keycloak for authentication (register, login etc...)
However I would like that once the account is created on Keycloak, in parallel an account is also created in the database (our database)
Because we will have a user field in db (last name, first name, username, avatar etc etc...)
Ideas ? Already done ? I take everything, thank you very much in advance! Have a good day

Comment: What technology are you using for backend?

Comment: I use NestJS @Jovana

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66242851/keycloak-to-save-newly-registered-user-into-application-database does this answers your question?